# Library references keeps disappearing

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have a WCF library project that I reference from a console app. The problem is every time I add the reference and it registers, it disappears in all of the following cases:

- If I rebuild either project
- If I try to run the console app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong target framework?

Go to your application's properties, click on the Compile tab and set the "Target framework (all configurations):" dropdown from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4"

See also:

[Visual Studio 2010 is Eating My DLLs! - referenced third party dlls missing after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247257/visual-studio-2010-is-eating-my-dlls-referenced-third-party-dlls-missing-after)

and:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

> If you are targeting the .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile, you cannot
>   reference an assembly that is not in
>   the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.
>   Instead you must target the .NET
>   Framework 4.
>   [...]
>
> ### **Features Not Included in the .NET Framework Client Profile**
>
> The .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile does not
>   include the following features. You
>   must install the .NET Framework 4 to
>   use these features in your
>   application:
>
> ASP.NET
>
> **Advanced Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) functionality**
>
> .NET Framework Data Provider for
>   Oracle
>
> MSBuild for compiling